# Large Monitor on Ubuntu Mate

Tags: screen, ubuntu

I have a large monitor which I'd like to use with the Raspberry Pi 2 Model B. The monitor is an LG 21:9 ultrawide so a little unusual.

I'm running Ubuntu Mate and the resolution is defaulting to 1824 x 984.

I realise this is optimistic but is there a driver which can handle larger screen sizes or is the onboard graphics just not up to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what worked for me in config.txt:

```
    hdmi_ignore_cec_init=1
hdmi_drive=2
disable_overscan=1

hdmi_ignore_edid=0xa5000080
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_timings=2560 1 64 64 96 1080 1 3 10 31 0 0 1 60 0 185580000 8

config_hdmi_boost=4

max_framebuffer_width=2560
max_framebuffer_height=1280
framebuffer_width=2560
framebuffer_height=1080

gpu_mem=128
arm_freq=900
gpu_freq=275
sdram_freq=500
hdmi_pixel_freq_limit=400000000
avoid_pwm_pll=1
```

output of `tvservice -s`:

```
state 0x12001a [HDMI DMT (87) RGB full unknown AR x1], 2560x1080 @ 60.00Hz, progressive
```

Comment: What flavor of Linux or does it not really matter?

Answer (score 5):

The maximum resolution the rPi can output (through its VideoCore IV chip) is 1920x1080. This is a 16:9 aspect ratio. [This link on raspberrypi.org](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=24679) shows that it is possible to get a 21:9 aspect ratio working - There are people that report being able to run at 2560x1080 on OpenELEC.

You will need to play with the HDMI timings in `config.txt`. Executing

```
tvservice -m DMT
```

will list the necessary parameters for your monitor.

The format of the new lines you need to add to config.txt is:

```
hdmi_cvt=<width> <height> <framerate> <aspect> <margins> <interlace> <rb>
width        width in pixels
height       height in pixels
framerate    framerate in Hz
aspect       aspect ratio 1=4:3, 2=14:9, 3=16:9, 4=5:4, 5=16:10, 6=15:9
margins      0=margins disabled, 1=margins enabled
interlace    0=progressive, 1=interlaced
rb           0=normal, 1=reduced blanking
```

Comment: +1 Also worth noting is the config.txt link that lists all supported resolutions: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt.md